# SQL Select SUM(col) from exec stored_proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, exec

Is there an easy way in SQL Server (2010) to exec a stored procedure (that returns a table) and sum a column in one (or a few) statements?

eg

```
SELECT SUM(column) FROM exec proc_GetSomeStuff 'param1', 'param2'
```

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730718/select-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have a server handy to test with, but try this:

```
declare @temp table(col1 int)

insert into @temp(col1)
exec proc_GetSomeStuff 'param1', 'param2'

select sum(col1) from @temp
```

Make sure your table variable (or temp table) has the same schema as the results of the stored procedure. If you know that there will be a significant number of rows coming back from the SP, then a temporary table might be a better option. (I'm not sure if table variables can be flushed out to disk if they get too big)

Comment: Does @temp have to have all the columns in the stored proc?  Just trying to avoid unnecessary typing.  go wales...

Comment: Hmm just tested and nope, have to add all columns to @temps.  Still should be a good solution

Comment: Yes table variables are allocated pages in `tempdb`, same as `#temp` tables and can be flushed to disc if big enough.