# SQL SELECT and Stored Procedure integration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SELECT FROM stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730718/select-from-stored-procedure)

How should I include a stored procedure in a T-SQL syntax?

```
select * from CITY_TABLE C where 
    COUNT_PEOPLE_PROCEDURE(C.ID) > 3
```

Comment: @Diego you can't say `SELECT ... WHERE EXEC someproc`...

Comment: @Diego OK, can you clean up your guesswork comments now so future readers don't think you're serious?

Comment: What duplicate? there is a complicated question, mine is much simpler, and there is no answer.

Comment: This is not asking about using a procedure as a data source; it is asking about using a procedure in a WHERE clause, which is conceptually quite different.  This is not a duplicate of [SO 3730718](http://stackoverflow.com/3730718).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot include stored procedure into query like this.

Instead, you can make scalar function

```
create function COUNT_PEOPLE_FUNCTION
(
    @ID int
)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @Result int

    <... your code here ...>

    return @Result
end
```

and then

```
select * from CITY_TABLE C where COUNT_PEOPLE_FUNCTION(C.ID) > 3
```

But, actually, it may slow your query, because scalar function will be called for each row independently.

Comment: I don't see any difference in select with my variant...

Comment: the only difference is that you have to create `function` and not `procedure`

Comment: @serhio look closer... that's a *function* not a *procedure*.

Comment: ok, **bold function** is better )

Comment: To remark, there is a need to specify **`DBO.`** `FUNCTION_NAME`

Comment: @serhio yes, you need to specify schema_name before function name when calling it

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, if you need to get the only records which have n occurrencies, you could use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CITY_TABLE WHERE IDPerson IN (
    SELECT IDPerson FROM CITY_TABLE GROUP BY IDPerson HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
)
```

Obviously i cannot know the exact column name, but this is the idea.

Comment: thank you, but I ask about stored procedures, not about a way to bypass it...

Comment: IMHO you can't use SP that way... you should use a function as stated above, with a big performance hit on large data sets.

Comment: I have a complicated select with multiple JOINs and I use this in multiple places in the sql... So I need to store it somewhere to use.

Comment: Ok, but your SP needs a parameter that is unique for each row of your initial select, is it correct? If so, you need an inline function, or a subquery.

Comment: However, playing with temporary tables & subqueries you could get a big performance improvement if compared to a scalar function.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said you cannot use a stored procedure like that, i suggest you to use a function if you can;
If you can't use a function (and even if you can) i suggest you this page as a useful reading:

[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: fortunately, I don't need to share data between SP, but thank you anyway for the article.

Comment: actually it could be useful, it says "How can I use the result set from a stored procedure in a SELECT statement?", by the way, as everybody says, you can't use SPs like the way you are using in your example